# Storekit Product.products: Failed to decode Product error

Tags: ios, swift, storekit2

I am using the StoreKit 2 Product.products() function to get the subscription products:

```
do {
    let product = try await Product.products(for: ["product_id"])
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The function throwing the following error:

> 2023-02-03 13:27:35.426740+0200 AppName[7101:1766595] [Default]
> [StoreKit:0e9a] Failed to decode Product: countMismatch(for:
> [StoreKit.Product.Key.attributes, StoreKit.Product.Key.offers,
> StoreKit.Product.Key.discounts], expected: Range(0..<2), actual: 2)

Would appreciate some help why I get this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you did not set the duration of the subscription order on appstoreconnect.com.
Go to appstoreconnect.com, select your app then under Feature select Subscriptions. Inside the `Group` you should have Subscriptions Order in a table format. Select the order item, On the new page you should see an option for `Subscription Duration`. Set it then save. It will probably take about 10-20 minutes to take effect.
[image]